# Shortest Query of Firebase in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to check if conversation child is exist.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(senderId);
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasChild("conversations")) {
                if (snapshot.child("conversations").hasChild(receiverId)) {
                    ConversationLocationModel conversationModel = snapshot.child("conversations").child(receiverId).getValue(ConversationLocationModel.class);
                    roomId = conversationModel.getLocation();
                    getAllMessage();
                } else {
                    addinLocation();
                }
            } else {
                addinLocation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

Currently I am using above code to check if child has exist i do not want to check every time so how it can be possible if there is any child exist is there any query for checking child existence.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if any child exists, then you can do this:

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(senderId).child("conversations");
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()){

          //checks if this snapshots exists
      }else{

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

You can change it depending on your database. But the above will check `child("users").child(senderId).child("conversations")` if conversations exists then it will enter it and see all its children.

Comment: yes but is it possible to check (If snapshot contain that child by using data reference directly)

Comment: you can add the child above, like this `child("users").child(senderId).child("conversations").child("childofconversation");` @Ashish

Comment: I tried but fail .. may be there is problem with my code

Comment: did u try this `child("users").child(senderId).child("conversations").child(receiverId);`

Comment: inside the if write this `ConversationLocationModel conversationModel = snapshot.getValue(ConversationLocationModel.class);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165050/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-ashish).

Comment: if it solved the problem, please upvote the answer and mark it as correct. Thank you!
@Ashish